# Применение Canvas ресурсов

Tags: wpf, xaml

Вопрос не привязан к какой-либо задаче, просто интересно, ответа в интернете не нашел пока. Имеются ресурсы вида:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="resources_icons_xaml"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Canvas x:Key="appbar_3d_3ds" Width="76" Height="76"
            Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="32" Height="40" Canvas.Left="23" Canvas.Top="18" Stretch="Fill"
              Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
              Data="F1 M 27,18L 23,26L 33,30L 24,38L 33,46L 23,50L
                    27,58L 45,58L 55,38L 45,18L 27,18 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

словарь в отдельном файле, и судя по всему это какие-то пиктограммы. Я хочу их применить к кнопке (пункту меню, просто к прямоугольнику)

Как и к каким свойствам их можно применить?

Comment: В каком смысле «ресурсы»? Чего именно вы хотите добиться? Расскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, для начала, вы *не сможете* так просто использовать ваш контрол, т. к. каждый контрол может иметь *не более одного родителя*. Вы должны прописать `x:Shared="False"`. Теперь вы можете использовать ваши ресурсы при помощи

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource appbar_3d_3ds}"/>
```

Но это на самом деле больше похоже на хак. Лучше оформить ваш XAML в отдельный `UserControl`, или стиль, или `DataTemplate`, в зависимости от того, для чего вам нужен этот код на самом деле.

Comment: если честно, ни для чего. В одном проекте-огрызке я увидел этот файл, но он пока нигде не применен, вот и стало интересно как, куда и так далее. Знания пока не позволяют сразу копать в нужном направлении, вот и задал вопрос

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov: В зависимости от того, для чего вам это надо, есть более подходящая техника для подобного. А так вообще да, по идее можно заставить работать пинками.

Comment: К сожалению данный проект создавался разработчиком, связаться с которым не представляется возможным. Может данный файл еще нужно чем-то дополнить. Ну ладно, большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov: Пожалуйста!